# Are there any good Virtual reality(daydream) android libraries?

Tags: android, virtual, daydream

I tried developing a app using jmini3d, though it is good and abstracts most of the code in https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk.There is not much documentation for jmini3d.Does any one know of any other libraries for VR(daydream) app development?

Answer (score 0):

Unity and Unreal are very popular for making VR applications on Daydream - is there anything you're looking to do that Unity/Unreal can't handle?

-Tom